# Remove all values before specific string in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a string array:

```
 string[] fruits = new string[];
```

fruits can contains these values (for the most part, the array can grow bigger or smaller. It's a dynamically filled array)

```
   [0] = "Apple"
   [1] = "Banana" 
   [2] = "Orange" 
   [3] = "Cantalope" 
   [4] = "Strawberry" 
   [5] = "BlueBerry"
   [6] = "Apple"
   [7] = "Banana" 
   [8] = "Orange" 
   [9] = "Apple"
   [10] = "Banana"
   [11] = "Orange" 
   [12] = "Cantalope" 
   [13] = "Strawberry" 
   [14] = "BlueBerry"
```

I was wondering what's the best approach removing all values before the last "Apple" in the array.

So the array now looks like:

```
   [0] = "Apple"
   [1] = "Banana"
   [2] = "Orange" 
   [3] = "Cantalope" 
   [4] = "Strawberry" 
   [5] = "BlueBerry"
```

Small attempt:

```
            if(fruits.Contains("Apple))
            {
                List<string> fruitsList = new List<string>(fruits);

               var appleTypeIndex =  fruitsList.LastIndexOf("Apple");

            }
```

Comment: LastIndexOf and then copy from there in a new list

Comment: Remove as in leave nulls there?  What have you tried?

Comment: Make a List<string>. Itterate over the array. Only add the elements you want to the List. List.ToArray().

Comment: copy them to new array from last apple  and then remove data from current array and get it back from new one.

Comment: Judging by the expected result you want the unique values rather than removing before the last apple? If that is the case you can also use `Distinct` (`fruits=fruits.Distinct().ToArray()`)

Comment: Please define *"best"*

Comment: @Stefan best practice in general. Like more efficient or more concise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the index of the last occurrence of "Apple" (improved per Euridice01's):

```
var lastAppleIndex = Array.LastIndexOf(fruits, "Apple");
```

Extract the fruits from the last "Apple" to the end (improved thanks to  Xiaoy312):

```
var afterAppleFruits = fruits.Skip(lastAppleIndex).ToArray();
```

### For large `fruits`

If `fruits` is very large, you would be better of with an `ArraySegment`:

```
var afterAppleFruits = new ArraySegment<string>(fruits, lastAppleIndex, fruits.Length-lastAppleIndex);
```

### Alternatively

I like extension methods, so here is one for `ArraySegment` creation:

```
public static ArraySegment<T> Slice<T>(this T[] src, int start, int? count = null) => (count.HasValue ? new ArraySegment<T>(src, start, count.Value) : new ArraySegment<T>(src, start, src.Length-start));
```

Then you can just say:

```
var afterAppleFruits = fruits.Slice(lastAppleIndex);
```

Comment: You don't need to use a projection from indexes, just `fruits.Skip(lastAppleIndex).ToArray()` will be enough

Comment: Nice. But I like projection from indexes :)

Comment: for lastAppleIndex, you can also use LastIndexOf("Apple").

Comment: @Euridice01 There is no `Array.LastIndexOf` in .Net/C#

Comment: Opps, you're right, only if you convert it to a list.

Comment: @Euridice01 No, you were right. I didn't see `Array.LastIndexOf` in the documentation initially.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 OTOH, if `fruits` were very large, `Skip` will be much worse than indexing (though `IEnumerable` friendly).

Comment: @NetMage it should be Array.LastIndexOf() instead of FindIndexOf() in your post. Also you have two statements with the same var. Should I be using ArraySegment and Slice or..? Thanks!

Comment: @Euridice01 You are right - I have multiple alternatives in my scratch pad and got confused about which is which. The two statements are just alternatives - depends on how you feel about adding extension methods (like `Slice`).

Answer (score 3):

Another "old fashioned" approach would be to insert items into a list by walking backwards through your array, until you get to "Apple", and the reassign your array to the new one:

```
string[] fruits = new string[]
{
    "Apple",
    "Banana",
    "Orange",
    "Cantalope",
    "Strawberry",
    "BlueBerry",
    "Apple",
    "Banana",
    "Orange",
    "Apple",
    "Banana",
    "Orange",
    "Cantalope",
    "Strawberry",
    "BlueBerry",
};

var lastFruits = new List<string>();

for (int i = fruits.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    lastFruits.Insert(0, fruits[i]);
    if (fruits[i] == "Apple") break;
}

fruits = lastFruits.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
        string[] fruits = new string[3];
        fruits[0] = "apple";
        fruits[1] = "orange";
        fruits[2] = "banana";

        IList<string> fruitList = fruits.ToList();

        // y index x string value
        foreach (var item in fruitList.Select((x, y) => new { x, y }))
        {
            if (item.x == "apple")
            {
                fruitList.RemoveAt(item.y);
            }
        }

        var result = fruitList;
```